# Using Custom Fields in Wordpress Templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-fields

I'm starting a WordPress website where I need the template to do a few things differently depending on the "Custom Fields" I set for each Page. The easiest way for me to do this is to have php values of the custom fields I set on those pages that I can then use throughout template files.

The closest thing I have found in [WP documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields) is:

```
<?php $key = "Random_Key_I_Need_Here" echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '$key', true); ?>
```

This echos the value of the key I need, but what I need is that value in a PHP value instead, so that I can use it throughout the template to dictate certain tags/content. Basically, how do I get exactly what the above script is doing in a PHP value instead of echo'ing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make it a variable.

```
$key = "Random_Key_I_Need_Here";
$metaValue = get_post_meta($post->ID, '$key', true);
```

Comment: I got so warped into trying to learn all this WordPress stuff.. I needed to take a step back. Whew. Thanks for bringing common sense back to me!